# How can I identify oneways at pgrouting

Tags: pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

I have set pgrouting and inserted my data with osm2pgrouting .

I would like to know how can I find out which way is one way.
Also I read that if I assign the reverse_cost of an one way to -1 only the this road is considered as one way, is it true?

Comment: Interesting. I would like to know too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.webrian.ch/2011/07/set-up-pgrouting-with-openstreetmap.html describes one possible solution. The challenge is that osm2pgrouting does not import one-way information. The author uses GRASS to find one-ways from the data. This solution sets reverse_cost to -1 to mark one-ways.

In pgRoutingDocs there is ["How to handle one-way streets"](http://download.osgeo.org/pgrouting/forum/pgrouting.postlbs.org/wiki/pgRoutingDocs/processing/advanced.html)
The idea there is to set the cost against the one-way direction very high (instead of -1).

Note: Only if the reverse parameter is set to true, the algorithms will use the reverse_cost field.

Osm2po, another OSM import tool, handles one-way information better. reverse_cost fields are filled automatically (to a very high value).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer, but I think that something might be wrong:

The osm2pgrouting code (Export2DB.cpp, called by osm2pgrouting.cpp) writes :

```
        if(way->oneway)
        row_data += TO_STR(way->length*1000000);
    else
        row_data += TO_STR(way->length);
```

but after exporting france.osm I notice that

> franceRouting=> select count (*) from ways where reverse_cost <>
>   length;
>   count -------
>        0 
>   (1 row)

So I guess that the condition (way->oneway) is not precise enough...
But "I might be wrong"!

=> Hell I did not send that answer?!
In the meantime I forked and modified the osm2pgrouting git repo. for it to consider the "oneway" tag values "true", "1" and "yes"... 
Maybe some more modifications are to come : the osm wiki states something like 'some ways, like motorways, are automatically considered as oneway edges'. 
Still, this statement can be taken into account afterwards with a single sql command...
HF!